# how to store multiple array values with using foreach?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I want to use foreach in my following code only one time.and i need to paas two array value that is store_data and store_control_text to my database respective fields.Need suggestions for not using foreach loop for multiple array values..

```
$data = $_REQUEST['columns_one'];
$controlText = $_REQUEST['controlText'];

$store_control_text = explode(",",$controlText);
$store_data = explode(",",$data);

$query = "INSERT INTO formdetailstemp(FormId,ControlType,ControlText,ControlPara1,Mandatory) VALUES ";
$values = array(); //store all the new rows
foreach($store_data as $key =>$value){
  $values[] = "('','".$value."','".$controlText."','".$controlPara."','".$mandatoryValue."')";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `array_map`

```
foreach ( array_map(null, $store_control_text, $store_data) as $join ) {
    list($text, $data) = $join;
     //Do your stuff 

}
```

[See Simple Example](http://codepad.org/B3sTgsl9)

Comment: This is at best a cryptic hack, attempting to mimic iterators, while doubling the memory usage that is necessary.

Comment: Not sure why you call it cryptic but PHP DOC says `array array_map ( callable $callback , array $arr1 [, array $... ] )`  See [Example #3 array_map() - using more arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) ...

Comment: Simple: `array_map()` is meant to apply a callback to one or more arrays, not iterate over two arrays, that's what iterators are for. It's cryptic because its functionality is non-obvious, and inefficient because you're doubling the memory usage when it's completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're looking for a [`MultipleIterator`](http://php.net/multipleiterator), which will iterate over both arrays easily with a single `foreach` loop:

```
$iter = new MultipleIterator;
$iter->attachIterator( new ArrayIterator( $store_control_text));
$iter->attachIterator( new ArrayIterator( $store_data));

foreach( $iter as $data) {
    list( $a, $b) = $data;
    var_dump( $a, $b);
    // Do your SQL insert with $a and $b
}
```

Comment: Can u suggest other option i m not comfortable in using multiple iterator?

Comment: @Sam - Why would you not be comfortable in using something that's designed for exactly what you need? If it's the first time you've seen it, read the documentation and try it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
you can use .implode();

foreach ($_POST['description'] as $row=>$name){
$description = $name;
$supplier = $_POST['supplier']; //Normal textbox value
$quantity = $_POST['quantity'][$row]; //Array text box 1
$partnumber = $_POST['partnumber'][$row]; // Array text box 2
$unitcost = $_POST['unitcost'][$row]; // Array text box 3

$sql_array[] = '("NULL","' . $partnumber . '","' . $supplier . '","'.$description.'", "'.$quantity.'","'.$unitcost.'")'; 
}

    $query_single = 'INSERT INTO `inwards` (`id`, `partnumber`, `suppliers`, `description`, `quantity`,`unitcost`) VALUES '. implode(', ', $sql_array);
```